# Different decorators for the same class

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have a decorator that takes arguments and I want to apply it to a class individually passing different arguments each time to create a separate different version of the same class. For example:

```
@decorator(arg1)
class SomeClass:
   pass

@decorator(arg2)
class SomeOtherClassWithSameContent:
    pass  # repetition of code here
```

How can I avoid creating two classes with the same functionality and avoid code repetition? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorators don't have to be applied literally using `@`:

```
class Foo:
    pass


SomeClass = decorator(arg1)(Foo)
SomeOtherClassWithSameContent = decorator(arg2)(Foo)
```

The `@` syntax is basically just shorthand for the above anyway.